# Animate.css issue: The page becomes super large

Tags: jquery, html, css, animate.css

I'm using animate.css to animate some elements, and with the class `fadeInRight` and `fadeInLeft`, a second before the animation is completed the bottom scroll bar appears (just for a fraction of a second).

I have been using that stylesheet for a while and this is the first time it happens.
I tried to do something with the function:

```
$(function(){
var width = window.innerWidth
$(body).css('max-width',width)});
```

but it doesn't fix anything.

Comment: body { overflow-x:hidden;}

Comment: JSFiddle or a demo would be awesome.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy That would hide everything overflowing the body including legitimate content.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that.

Comment: body { overflow-x:hidden;} completely prevents the animation. But just the fadeinLeft and Rignt, because other tipes of animations work, it's as though the fadeineft and Right needs a track to start from, and the starting point is outside of the page.

Comment: body { overflow-x:hidden;} is fine, it doesn't affect any legitimate content, but with that the animation doesn't even start

Comment: Ok @Ohgodwhy, you can post body { overflow-x:hidden;} as an answer, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `body { overflow-x:hidden;}`

You can also use `{position:relative; overflow-x:hidden}` on any parent element that contains the animations as a work around for the issue you described above.